# Eclipse can't open file given as argument

Tags: c++, eclipse, ifstream, argv

I have a really simple code snippet accessing a file and doing something with its content:

```
void MyClass::initialize( string filePath )
{
    ifstream inputFile;

    inputFile.open( filePath.c_str(), fstream::in );

    if( inputFile.is_open() )
    {

            //do something
    }else{
            cout << "Error: not able to open input file [" << filePath << "]" << endl;
    }
}
```

The project containing this code snippet compiles successfully on Eclipse (as well if I use my own makefile from terminal) but when I try to run it I have two different behaviors:

1. With terminal, e.g. `./test ../workDir/inputFile`, the program runs correctly and accesses the content of the file with that path.
2. With Eclipse, after setting the Input Arguments in Run->Configurations->Arguments to `../workDir/inputFile` I get prompted with the following error:

> Error: not able to open input file [../workDir/inputFile]

I believe it's not a problem in my code since it runs without errors when I launch from terminal, so what is the problem in the way I define arguments for Eclipse?  Is there a particular way of opening files from the IDE?

Comment: try providing a full path to the file.  the likely issue is that the working directory that the executable file is run from its not as you expect and the relative path to the file is therefore incorrect.

Comment: @RobKielty - looks like you are right, using the absolute path solved the problem.  This means that eclipse doesn't use the directory of the binary file as the directory from where start the search.  At this point the question is do you know which is the directory to consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse (and AFAIK every other IDE I have used) runs your program from the project directory, but stores the executable someplace else.

To execute your project as ./test, you are in the "executable someplace else" directory.

From what you say, the correct path to run from the IDE would be WorkDir/inputfile, because WorkDir is in your project directory, right?